# Asking to work from home and a pay raise

Tags: salary, telecommute

My apartment lease is up in a few months and I have been looking for a job in another state to be closer to family. I don't hate my current job but I feel I am underpaid for a software engineer with the number of years of experience that I have. I haven't been able to secure a new job yet and I am running out of time. In the event that I do not have a job by the time my lease runs out, I am not sure what I should do. I could ask them to let me work from home in another state and come in occasionally if I need to be there but I'd still be unhappy with my pay. Its a lot to ask for a pay raise and full time work from home. I'd imagine it could backfire to let them know that I am looking for another job. I am just looking for some guidance.

Comment: Your going to need to explain what WFH stands for exactly

Comment: WFH = work from home, I would think

Comment: Yes WFH is work from home. Extending my lease is probably the safest option I agree.

Comment: A lot of people who rent apartments can stay month-to-month once their lease term expires without extending for a new term.  Is that a possibility for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd imagine it could backfire to let them know that I am looking for
>   another job.

How would they equate your asking for a raise and asking to work from home with your looking for a new job? Is your employer omniscient?

If you feel like a raise is justified then ask for it, and detail your justifications for it. If you want to work from home then ask for it, and detail your reasons for wanting to work from home.

For the time being, if it were me, I'd renew my lease or see if my lease could be converted to month-to-month.

Comment: +1 " I feel I am underpaid for a software engineer with the number of years of experience that I have" - raises are determined by the value you bring to the company, not the length of service, you need to show you are worth that raise..